# Travis: define OS specific environment variables

Tags: linux, travis-ci

I'm using Go lang in my project and Travis-CI to build it.

I want to build it on each operating system (OSX, Linux, Windows) so I wanted to use `GIMME_OS` and `GIMME_ARCH` environment variables ([from GIMME project](https://github.com/travis-ci/gimme)) but the problem is that Darwin is not sufficient for my project so I must build my project on mac natively.

My approach is to build OSX operating system as VM ( travis supports this directly from the .travis.yml file ) and to build on linux using cross-compilation (GIMME) linux64, linux386 & windows.

For now each time I'm defining an environment variable it created a new column for my build matrix. I want environment variables that will hold o**nly in the linux build part**.

For now my .travis.yml looks like this:

```
language: go

go:
    - 1.4.2

os:
    - osx
    - linux

env:
    - GIMME_OS=windows GIMME_ARCH=amd64
    - GIMME_OS=linux GIMME_ARCH=amd64
    - GIMME_OS=linux GIMME_ARCH=386
    - GIMME_OS=darwin GIMME_ARCH=386

  matrix:
     exclude:
          os: osx
          env: GIMME_OS=darwin GIMME_ARCH=386

before_script:
    - go get -d -v ./...

script:
    - go build -v ./...
    - go test -v ./...
```

This really created **8** builds (each environment variable row for each OS)
Is there a way to define environment variables that will be relevant only for some sections in the .travis.yml file (specifically OS section)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of defining an OS name yourself you could use `$TRAVIS_OS_NAME` which is either osx or linux. [Docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables#Default-Environment-Variables)
Your 'env' section would then simplify to only two lines for arch.

In general there's no way to define OS dependent variables from the yml. A nice way to solve this would be to have `.travis.${TRAVIS_OS_NAME}.env` files in your repo and to source those before the first build step needs it.